# Issue with the logo and its position using media queries

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, responsive

As the title states my logo for this assignment needs to be in certain areas of the screen in different screen sizes. I have the mobile positioning correctly implemented but I can't seem to find a solution the positioning of the logo for ipad and larger screens.

For large screens the logo needs to be centered directly above the first `.product` element, which in my case is the *A as in Apple*

[image]

For ipad screens the logo needs to be halfway between the left edge of the screen and the centered `h1` element

[image]

No matter what I try the logo just stays fixed the left.

I realize that in `css` its position is set to `float:left` but I've changed it to `display:flex` and the various `flexbox` properties, but it ended up creating more of a problem. I've changed the logo position in each `@media query` but the logo always ended up staying in place or way off from where it needs to be.

I understand that google is my best friend but I've exhausted all possible methods and have reached my last resort. The last I wanted to do was get stuck and immediately post here without at least trying for several hours. Forgive me for the newbie and probably obvious question but I'm at my wits end and really need help . Thank you.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body>i> {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

body>header> {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo>img {
  width: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.product {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo {
    float: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  main {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/6eb75550-4d51-47fd-8ec1-d216b5da5e5c/M4sq-logo.jpeg" /></div>
    <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
      <p>
        We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App, the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry. This is the Uber of Apples!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
      <p>
        Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the Facebook of bail bonds!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

      <p>
        Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**fragment header into 3 equals parts**

```
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

**make logo image center**

```
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**make heading nowrap**

```
header h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Look into the snippet how it looks. I commented all floatings and absolute positioning in meadia query.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body>i> {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

body>header> {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo>img {
  width: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.product {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

header h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  /*.logo {
    float: left;
  }*/
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  /*.logo {
    float: left;
  }*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /*.logo {
    float: none;
  }*/
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  header {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  main {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  /*.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25;
  }*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/6eb75550-4d51-47fd-8ec1-d216b5da5e5c/M4sq-logo.jpeg" /></div>
    <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
      <p>
        We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App, the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry. This is the Uber of Apples!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
      <p>
        Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the Facebook of bail bonds!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

      <p>
        Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is certainly a step in the right direction. I was going to try from scratch and go from there. Everything is perfect except the logo in smartphone (500px)media query. The logo needs to be above the header. Im incredibly new at web development so my apologies . It needs to look like this @500px  https://i.imgur.com/NF1u0Gg.png

Comment: @danuma just add `header {display: block;}` to `@media screen and (max-width: 500px)` Updated answer

Comment: @danuma I really appriciate an upvote, if you think I deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

First sorry my English, I am not fluent, my solution proposal, I took the liberty to change some things in your css.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<style>
    *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
    color: white;
}
    
.hamburger {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: none;
}
    
.social {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-around; 
    border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
    }
.menu{
    display: inherit;
    list-style: none;
}
    
    
.navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
    
.product {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 30px;
    padding:10px;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    
}

header h1 {
    display: inherit;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}



.logo{
    display: inherit;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.logo > img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .hamburger {
      display: none;
    }
    main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
 
    .product {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      align-self: center;
      align-content: center;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 50vw;
      text-align: center;
    }
}

@media (max-width:700px){
    .navbar ul li{
        display: none;
    }
    .hamburger{
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px){
    header h1 {
        display: inherit;
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-content: center;
        align-self: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
</style>
<body>
  <header>
        <div class="logo"><img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/6eb75550-4d51-47fd-8ec1-d216b5da5e5c/M4sq-logo.jpeg"/></div>
        <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Help</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
    <section class="product">
         <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-5x"></i>
            <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
            <p>
            We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why
            the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App,
            the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry.
            This is the Uber of Apples! 
            </p>
        </section>
        <section class="product">
            <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
            <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
            <p>
                Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you
                with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the 
                Facebook of bail bonds!
            </p>
        </section>
        <section class="product">
            <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
            <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

            <p>
                Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry
                cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
            </p>
        </section>
    </main>
  <footer>
        <ul class="social">
            <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
            <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
            <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That got the logo where it needed to go for the desktop and tablet media queries but for mobile the logo needs to go above the header like so  https://imgur.com/NF1u0Gg   The help is much appreciated however, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice solution using flexbox or css grid:

Steps to resolve the problem:

1. Remove the class `.logo` from the media queries.
2. Implement the solution in the header element like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.logo>img {
  width: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.product {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
      flex-flow: column
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  main {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/6eb75550-4d51-47fd-8ec1-d216b5da5e5c/M4sq-logo.jpeg" /></div>
    <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
      <p>
        We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App, the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry. This is the Uber of Apples!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
      <p>
        Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the Facebook of bail bonds!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

      <p>
        Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need to keep the text in the middle of the header, just use css grid instead.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.logo>img {
  width: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-top: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  line-height: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.product {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  main {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/6eb75550-4d51-47fd-8ec1-d216b5da5e5c/M4sq-logo.jpeg" /></div>
    <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
      <p>
        We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App, the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry. This is the Uber of Apples!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
      <p>
        Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the Facebook of bail bonds!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

      <p>
        Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think with a combination of everything mentioned in everyone's post I believe the issue has been resolved. In order to lower the logo I used  position: relative in each @media query. I realize the underlying issue here is my inexperience but thank you to all that helped me with this problem.